# Rails 3 - Change HTTP Status to 200 and add status to response body

Tags: flash, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to catch the HTTP response just as it's leaving rails and rewrite as follows:

1. Create a root status node with the status code in it, then
2. Rewrite the header status to 200

Eg. For all responses, put their status as a root node and then rewrite their header:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type:text/html

This page was not found
```

Into this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<status='404'>
This page was not found
</status>
```

Background:
Using Rails 3 with a Flash client.

Anything other than HTTP 200 cannot be guaranteed to pass through to the client due to limitations of browsers. Some allow 201 through, but not all. Also, any headers will be stripped off most of the time, with only the body getting through.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Rack-Middleware since its really easy to process the header and rewrite the body.
Put this into `app/middleware/flashfix.rb`

```
    class FlashFix
      def initialize(app)
        @app = app
      end

      def call(env)
        status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
        if status == 404 
          [200, headers, "<status='404'>" + response.body + "</status>"]
        else
          [status, headers, response]      
        end
      end
    end
```

This just checks if Rails returns a response with the status code "404" and then rewrites the the response accordingly.
Then inside an intializer:

```
     # Loops through all middlewares and requires them
     Dir[File.join(Rails.root,"app/middleware/*.rb")].each do |middleware|
       require middleware
     end
```

With the middleware in place all you need to do is tell Rails to use it

```
    class Application < Rails::Application
      config.middleware.use "FlashFix"          
    end
```

If you are unfamiliar with Rack I recommend http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Comment: I've tried what you've written and I can't get it to work.
Sometimes the `response` object is an `Array`, sometimes it is an `ActionDispatch::Response`, in either case I haven't been able to work with it.

I've also tried just rewriting the status:
`status, headers, response = @app.call(env)`
`[200, headers, response]`

Comment: ...and that didn't work either.

I needed to use an alternative way to get the module loaded though, so maybe that's part of the problem. Where in the rails tree am I meant to put the file example you gave? eg. /lib/rack/flash_fix.rb ?